# How to forward headers between microservices in nestJs

Tags: nestjs

I have a NestJS project composed of microservices that communicate with each other over TCP. I want to attach the logId generated in the Gateway to the headers and pass it on to other microservices. Additionally, I want to retrieve this logId within the microservice that receives the information, without changing my current structure, i.e., without adding extra header parameters to each request. How can I do this? Currently, I'm calling my other microservice like this.

```
const responseDistributor: IResponse = await firstValueFrom(
  this.cudioServiceClient.send(
    DistributorEventName.GET_BY_ID,
    distributorId
  ),
);
```

I added the logId to the header in the interceptor, but I couldn't figure out how to pass it to the microservices or how to use it. Can you help me with this?

```
    @Injectable()
    export class LoggingInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>> {
    constructor() { }

    async intercept(ctx: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler):Promise<Observable<any>> {
       const [req] = ctx.getArgs();
       const logId = uuidv4();
     ...
```